# Is it possible to get data from magento with out authentication using REST API?

Tags: php, rest, cron, magento-1.9

Currently I am getting required data from Magento using REST API, but I have to get these data with out asking login and authorization. How can I do this?

For more details follow [the link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/78168/how-to-get-customers-data-from-magento-using-rest-api-without-authentication-is).

Answer (score 0):

That's what the "Guest" role was created for.

Go in to `System > Web Services > REST - Roles > Guest` and make sure the endpoint you want to use is enabled for Guest access. Then go to `System > Web Services > REST - Attributes > Guest` and make sure all the attributes you're trying to access are also enabled. You should now be able to load data from the relevant URL without supplying any credentials.